# Pandas Excel Writer append mode is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I created a pandas dataframe in my code and tried to append the final output to an existing Excel workbook. The existing workbook is called "Directory" and has three different sheets in it. I want to append my output to one of the sheets called "raw_data in the workbook". This sheet already has some data in it but the columns in this sheet match the columns in my new dataframe. Here is my code:

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
from openpyxl import Workbook

with pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\Documents\Directory.xlsx', engine ='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'raw_data',  index = False, header = False)
    writer.save()

writer.close()
```

My code "runs" without any error but when I check the workbook after running the code, my code doesn't append my data frame to the specified sheet, "raw_data", but creates a new sheets called "raw_data1" and store the data in that tab. I couldn't figure out which part in my code is incorrect. Could anyone please help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you need writer.save() and writer.close()? The context manager should take care of that automatically shouldn't it?

Comment: Also, you haven't actually imported pandas as pd in your code sample but you've used the alias (pd.ExcelWriter). Is that just a misprint?